# Customizing Joomla template

Tags: templates, joomla, header, customization

Good day!

Could you help me to figure out how to customize joomla 2.5 template. The problem is that main(index page) shouldn't contain header block, but other pages should. Is there any solution for this (maybe somewhere in administration panel located this option). Sorry for my bad english and pure knowledge of joomla.

Comment: Check this resource http://docs.joomla.org/ good place to start joomla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could help if you could show me your site,
but one easy option would be to use following to test for front page in your template:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        echo 'This is the front page';
}
?>
```

another option would be to prevent all header modules from showing on the front page (if your header is made of modules)

Comment: Thanks! Here is site [link](http://glek.com.ua). I have to made same on Joomla. On that site index page doesn't contain header, but others does.

Comment: No, but I discovered that I can use two different templates. So for index page I'll use template without header and with header for other. Thanks for your time spending on me :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different templates and assign one of them to your front page and make the second one default, so it will be assigned to the rest of your pages.  However, you wouldn't normally do that if the only thing that's different is the presence of the header and everything else (like layout, colors, shapes, etc.) is the same.
In your case it makes more sense to implement your header as a module (use "Custom HTML" module type) and set it up to only display on the front page.

Good luck!
удачи!